Messed up Ubuntu 24.04 upgrade and can't even reach grub menu; what can I do?
I followed a guide to upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04 since I actually needed some fixes they introduced in it. The guide was pretty straightforward. It just had me do sudo apt update and upgrade, etc, and then sudo do-release-upgrade -d (it didn't work without -d).
It downloaded everything, seemed to be going well, but at some point I came back and it had the dreaded white "oh no! something went wrong" white screen.
At that point, I could still do ctrl+alt+f2 to get to a shell. Some things were funky, like when I tried to do sudo apt update from there, it said unable to resolve host temporary failure in name resolution. But I followed a guide what seemed to be fixing broken packages with apt and dpkg, and it seemed to be working, so I did a reboot.
Now I can't even get to the grub screen. When I turn on the computer, it brings me to my BIOS menu, and if I exit that, it just reboots again in an infinite loop.
I logged in with a live Ubuntu USB, and did boot-repair, just doing the standard one. Again it seemed to work, but rebooting, the problem remains.
Is there anything I can do? can I somehow repair whatever has been messed up, by using the live USB stick? how can I even figure out what is wrong if I can't get to a shell?

Same problem here. I upgraded from 22.04 LTS to 24.04 LTS. I am using a Lenovo IdeaPad 5i Pro from 2023. My laptop shows the Lenovo logo, immediately turns off, turns on again and directly boots into bios. I can't do anything else.

I did exactly what you did, and I'm also stuck in the same spot.

UPDATE: I ran boot-repair, was able to get back to the white screen, then ran apt upgrade followed by apt autoremove. During upgrade, I opted to let grub overwrite the config file for memory test because why not.
After reboot, I was able to get in, networking was messed up, found an article others having the same issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/2055012 and in there was apt install systemd-resolved. I'm now able to post this response from my repaired computer.

@Blakethepatton that's great news. Did you do anything special during the boot-repair ? I did the default thing but it didn't fix anything... I fear I borked it more than you did during my initial repair attempt.

ok, by booting into the live USB and mounting my ubuntu partition in /dev/, I'm able to see and access the files from my original ubuntu partition. So I know they're not corrupted or something. Does that imply that the problem is definitely something with grub?

@MasterZibZob I had to decrypt my main partition as it is encrypted with luks, but other than that I copied and pasted the commands as instructed by boot-repair. Maybe worth mentioning that I was running boot-repair in a Ubuntu 24 live environment. Pretty simple to install the utility.

There is one thing I forgot to mention, I doubt it had much effect but who knows, once I got booting back I still had the white screen of death, after switching to a terminal and running apt upgrade and auto remove, I ran startx and that booted the desktop environment. After which I think I rebooted to see if everything was working.

This usually happens when the EFI entry for grub has been removed from the bios, I have had it happen a few times, run the ubuntu installer and choose try ubuntu and use the ubuntu startup repair tool
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
if that doesn't work you may need to look search for ubuntu EFI repair guides but be warned it can be tricky to get it working correctly.
